# Python "module not found" error when importing from folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the common problem of the "module not found" error when trying to import a file within a folder in my project directory as a package. I've tried several solutions from Stackoverflow answers, but none are working for me. Here's what's going on, and what I've tried:

I'm working in a conda environment `devenv` on a Flask project, using PyCharm, and have a project directory like this:

```
/some/path/project_root/
    migrations/
    static/
    templates/
    reporting/
       __init__.py
       code.py
       tests.py
```

Inside the `tests.py` file there are import statements to import `code.py` as a module:

```
from .code import my_function
```

However, when I run `(devenv) me@comp:project_root$ > python reporting/tests.py`

I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.code'; '__main__' is not a package`

I tried appending the project directory path to $PYTHONPATH, and `echo $PYTHONPATH` returns `/some/path/project_root/`

What do I need to configure to get this to work properly? Also, whatever settings I need to change, can I make those settings specific to the development environment I'm using?