# Importing files from same folder, module not found

Tags: python, plugins

I have a directory called login which contains two modules: `login.py` and `credentials.py`. When i try to import `credentials.py` into `login.py` I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'credentials'
```

I have looked on the solution sugested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179049/python-module-not-found-error-when-importing-from-folder).

and also tried importing it as if it ws from a different directory:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"C:\\Users\\carmel.han\\AppData\\Roaming\\QGIS\\QGIS3\\profiles\\default\\python\\plugins/login/credentials.ini")
import credentials
```

Still does not work. This is a reoccuring problem I have in my code.
Does sombody have an idea?

Comment: Your file is called `credentials.ini` or `credentials.py`?

Comment: os.chdir() may solve your problem, did you try it?